# Accessing Backend application through API with Okta

Tags: authentication, authorization, okta, okta-api

So i'm using Okta to authenticate end users (resource owners) so they can SS0 in to any integrate it application (within okta)..but now i also want to access the API's of the backend resources using Okta(not goint straight to the API of the application). Is there a way i could achieve this?

Taking the basic scope of okta,(having a centralize place where users can SSO to any application)..can i also do this but using the application API's ?(So application A and B can share resources with the same credentials that the user used to sign in to Okta).

Note: I've used the okta API for managing the users in the okta's directory, but im actually trying to access the application(s) that sits in okta using the api(Jira,salesforce,etc)